# Modify all resource strings with a prefix to easily spot i18n or RTL issues

Tags: .net, localization, resources, internationalization, pseudolocalization

I want to easily (ie: not manually touch every string) add a prefix to all of my resource strings, something like 'XXXSomeString', such that I can spot both non-localized strings (they won't have the prefix) or not RTL compatible forms (the prefix will be on the left).

Is there a tool to do this, or maybe a way to modify the resource code file to add the prefix when every string value is returned?  Or if you have a better solution for this problem, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a technique called [pseudolocalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudolocalization) which does this. See this other question for existing tools that you can find for .NET: [ASP.NET MVC pseudo-localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673529/asp-net-mvc-pseudo-localization)

**Edit**

To add to this in relation to your point about RTL (right-to-left), pseudolocalization can do this too, and in Windows there is a specific "Mirrored" pseudo-locale (named `qps-plocm`, where regular pseudo is `qps-ploc`), as per [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'm not aware of an existing publicly available tool to generate mirrored pseudolocalized resources though, but maybe I haven't looked hard enough.

Comment: You can use http://www.pseudolocalize.com to quickly translate strings to pseudolocalized text.  A couple copy/paste commands and you can have a whole "translated" file.